# Why id the program returning "Signature invalid?"

Tags: c++, encryption, key, aes, libsodium

I use this program to encrypt a message (program arguments: "Sign Message") and decrypt it with libsodium I tried bith variants crypto sign and crypto_sign_detached but it always fails verifying the message.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
#include <iomanip>
#include <sodium.h>
#include <sstream>


using namespace std;

void HexStringToArray ( const char * const text , unsigned char a[] , const size_t array_size )
{
for ( size_t i = 0; i < array_size ; i ++)
{
const string text_part ( text + 2 * i , 2) ; // Process 2 chars at a time
stringstream s ( text_part ) ;
s >> hex ;
int value ;
s >> value ;
a[i] = char(value) ;
}
}

int main(const int argc, const char * const argv[])
{
if (sodium_init() == -1)
return 1;

if(strcmp(argv[1],"Sign")==0) //Das Programm signiert eine Nachricht
{
    const char * const message = argv[2];//Nachricht
    const size_t message_length = sizeof(message)+1;//Nachrichtenlänge in bytes: warum muss man +1 addieren damit auch die letzte Buchstage gelesen wird?
    unsigned char* m;
    m = (unsigned char*) message;//Konvertierung der Nachricht im benötigten Format

    unsigned char pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
    unsigned char sk[crypto_sign_SECRETKEYBYTES];
    crypto_sign_keypair(pk, sk);//generate keys
    //convert signed message to hex
    stringstream s;
        s<<hex ;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof pk; i++)
    s << setw (2) << setfill ('0') << (int)pk[i];


    unsigned char signed_message[crypto_sign_BYTES + message_length];
    unsigned long long signed_message_len;
    crypto_sign(signed_message, &signed_message_len,m,message_length, sk);

    //convert key to hex
    stringstream t;
    t<<hex ;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof signed_message; i++)
    t << setw (2) << setfill ('0') << ( int )signed_message[i];

    cout<<endl<<"Signed Message: "<<t.str();//hex
    cout<<endl<<"Public key: "<<s.str();
}


  else if(strcmp(argv[1],"Verify")==0)
  {

 unsigned char unsigned_message[strlen(argv[2])];//Länge Nachricht plaintext
 unsigned long long unsigned_message_len;
 const char * const signed_message_hexa=argv[3];

 const char * const pk_hexa=argv[4];
 //Hexa in char/ libsodium umwandeln

 //signed_message_hexa
 unsigned char signed_message[crypto_sign_BYTES + strlen(argv[2])];
 for ( size_t i = 0; i < strlen(signed_message_hexa)/2 ; i ++)
 {
    const string text_part ( signed_message_hexa + 2 * i , 2) ;
    stringstream s ( text_part ) ;
    s >> hex ;
    int value ;
    s >> value ;
    signed_message[i]=value;
 }
 //pk
 unsigned char pk[crypto_sign_PUBLICKEYBYTES];
 for ( size_t i = 0; i < strlen(pk_hexa)/2 ; i ++)
 {
    const string text_part ( pk_hexa + 2 * i , 2) ;
    stringstream s ( text_part ) ;
    s >> hex ;
    int value ;
    s >> value ;
    pk[i]=value;
 }


 unsigned long long signed_message_len=crypto_sign_BYTES + strlen(argv[2]);
 if (crypto_sign_open(unsigned_message, &unsigned_message_len,signed_message, signed_message_len, pk) != 0)
    cout<<"Signature invalid";
    else cout<<"Signature valid";
  (void) argc;
  return 0;
}}
```

I start the program with the arguments

> Sign Message

it returns

> Signed Message: d93c44fd742e01c64a388862aa11e06dbb7081a2b4e226e78e9574b342dfb99bb2c4d188722faea49df2d2ed426131181d381923649144053dcd07ec46e2460d4d6573736167650055
>
> Public key: 9e649d74d1852ce6396b0f0a680e567f8663c2f6c3edacd0ba41db29f562066a

Then I start it with

> Verify Message d93c44fd742e01c64a388862aa11e06dbb7081a2b4e226e78e9574b342dfb99bb2c4d188722faea49df2d2ed426131181d381923649144053dcd07ec46e2460d4d6573736167650055 9e649d74d1852ce6396b0f0a680e567f8663c2f6c3edacd0ba41db29f562066a

and it returns

> Signature invalid

Is there a conversion error or maybe I use in a wrong mode the arguments?

Thank you a lot!

Comment: `sizeof(message)` doesn't do what you think it does. It calculates the size of a pointer variable.

Comment: Thank you! Should I use strlen(message) instead?

Comment: Because only changing the sizeof(message) to strlen(message) didn's solve the problem...